# Self-dual object in tensor triangulated categories which are not strongly dualizable

Tags: tensor-products, duality-theorems, monoidal-categories, triangulated-categories

I am working in a closed symmetric tensor triangulated category. This is a triangulated category $\mathcal{T}$ admitting a symmetric monoidal structure with tensor product $\otimes$ which is closed. That is, for any $X \in \mathcal{T}$ the functor $X\otimes -$ admits a right adjoint $F(X,-)$. Also, we want these functors to respect the triangulated structure.
I won't repeat all the details of the definitions since they are easily available in the literature.

Famous examples are $(D(R), \otimes, R)$ the derived category of $R$-modules (where $R$ is a ring) with the tensor product induced by the one on chains, $(\mathcal{S}p, \wedge, S^0)$ the stable homotopy category with the smash product.

In this setting we declare an object $X \in \mathcal{T}$ to be strongly dualizable if for any other object $Y$ we have $F(X,Y)\cong DX\otimes Y$, where $DX=F(X,1)$ is the dual of $X$. It is classical that these objects are really interesting and have been studies toughly.

It is folklore that if $X$ is strongly dualizable then $X\cong DDX$. I was wondering: does the converse hold? I.e. if the canonical map $X\rightarrow DDX$ (induced from adjunction unit) is an isomorphism does this imply $X$ is strongly dualizable? I would suppose this if this is true then such characterization would appear in the literature and I could not find it anywhere. But I cannot think of a counterexample on top of my head. I suppose counterexamples exist but are not trivial.

There is another similar matter: it happens that some objects are self-dual (up to a translation), that is $X\cong \Sigma^i DX$ for some $i \in \mathbb{Z}$. For example, the unit is trivially self-dual $F(1,1)\cong 1$, in the stable homotopy category the mod-$p$ Moore spectrum $S/p$ satisfies $DS/p\cong\Sigma^{-1}S/p$. If an object is self-dual is it necessarily strongly dualizable? Again I would believe there are non-trivial counterexamples.

Comment: I doubt it. Consider $\bigoplus_{n} \Sigma^n R$ in $D(R)$. This is an unbounded object, so it's not dualizable. On the other hand it is self-dual because you can take the $\bigoplus$ out, and since $D(D(\Sigma^n R)) = \Sigma^n R$. This example also answers your follow-up question since $R$ itself is self-dual. (You'll want to make sure that the $\bigoplus$ ranges over all of $\mathbb{Z}$ though.)